# Installing Older Version of Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I wish to install Zend Framework 1.5.2 on my Linux Fedora 14 with php 5.2.6.

I got Zend Framework 1.5.2 release from

```
 http://framework.zend.com/download/archives
```

The issue now is, I don't see any make install file Zend Framework folder. If I use zf in ssh/putty it will install newest version of Zend Framework not 1.5.2 and it will update php to newest version. I however do not want to update php because my codes will stop working, and latest ZF does not match with structure of older ZF.

For a newbie, can you explain how to install ZF 1.5.2 WITHOUT the make file in there, or am I just blind and it is there? It says just copy it and include it into your include_path. my zend library is in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/library, my php.ini file is in /etc/php.ini .

I included "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/library" into the include_path of php.ini and restarted server. It's giving me an error when I try to load index page. (will post in 2 minutes).

Comment: Issue is resolved. PHP and MySQL have to be older versions. PHP 5.2.6 and the matching MySQL version for it too. Otherwise it should work fine.

Comment: The link http://framework.zend.com/download/archives is not active any more.

Answer (score 2):

zend framework installation is basicly coping files and folders to your server and pointed to this folder in your application, also extending include_path